# Use HTML input 'name' attribute to yield an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

In *ExpressJS* using *body-parser*, there exists the functionality to parse as a JavaScript object (or JSON, I'm not entirely sure) a set of input elements which have the same name attribute with defined keys.

**HTML (e.g.)**:

```
<input type="text" class="name" name="name[foo]" placeholder="input1"/>
<input type="text" class="name" name="name[bar]" placeholder="input2"/>
```

**JavaScript (e.g.)**:

```
var obj = req.body.name;
```

The object `obj` is understood by JavaScript to be `{ "foo" : input1, "bar" : input2 }`

I am trying to get similar functionality using standard jQuery to handle several related form inputs.  What I have tried so far—to no avail—is the following:

`$(".name")` yields an Object containing the literal HTML (not helpful for grabbing the key-value pairs).

`$(".name").map(function () {return $(this).val();}).get();` yields an *array* of values, but no keys.

`$("input[name='name']")` and `$("input[name='name[]']")` yield nothing.

I have also tried the following to convert the inputs to an array, but it still does not serve the purpose of pulling the information from the form as a JavaScript object/JSON:

```
$.fn.inputsToArray = function () {
  var values= [];
  $.each(this, function (i, field) {
    values.push(field.value);
  });
  return values;
};
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do without *NodeJS* / *body-parser*?

---

**Solution:**

Thanks to [gaetanoM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3880585/gaetanom)'s excellent solution (accepted below), I was able to create a generic jQuery function that can be called on any jQuery object (obviously, it'll only work properly if the element is in the `<input ... name="example[key]" ... />` format, but I digress).

The function is called thusly:

```
var output = $(":input[name^=example]").inputsToObject();
```

The function is defined as the following:

```
$.fn.inputsToObject = function () {
  var values = {};
  values = $(this).get().reduce(function (acc, ele) {
    var key = ele.name.match(/\[(.*)\]$/)[1];
    acc[key] = $(ele).val();
    return acc;
  }, {})
  return values;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first you need [$(':input[name^=name]')](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) in order to select all input fields having the name attribute starting with name. With [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/) you transform the jQuery result into an array on which you can apply [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control):

```js
var result = $(':input[name^=name]').get().reduce(function(acc, ele) {
    var key = ele.name.match(/\[(.*)\]$/)[1];  // get the key
    acc[key] = ele.getAttribute('placeholder'); // add to retval
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" class="name" name="name[foo]" placeholder="input1"/>
<input type="text" class="name" name="name[bar]" placeholder="input2"/>
```

Comment: This was an incredibly helpful solution.  I've adapted it to add it to a jQuery method, so for those who wish to add it as a generic method, the code is below.

    `$.fn.inputsToObject = function () {
      var vals = $(this).get().reduce(function (acc, ele) {
        var key = ele.name.match(/\[(.*)\]$/)[1];
        acc[key] = $(ele).val();
        return acc;
      }, {})
      return vals;
    }`

Call it thusly:

    `var objectOutput = $(":input[name^=name]").inputsToObject();`

Comment: @Mattallurgy  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking around on how to get a list of objects, try something like this

```
<input name={`attributes[${index}][${key}]`} />
<input name={`attributes[${index}][${key2}]`} />
```

where `index` is the index of the object in the `formdata.attributes` array, `key/key2` is the key in that object, and the input `value` will set the value for that key

result will be

```
attributes: [{key: 'foo', key2: 'bar'}]
```